# Search Bar won't work in Safari?

Tags: html, css, safari

Ok, I'm not sure what to do. I have this search bar issue. My site is kissoff.weebly.com and the site works in IE, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Seamonkey-- but it's not safari-compatible due to the search bar.

I need to push the search bar over to the right, just like how it should look in IE, Chrome, Firefox, Opera. Here's a screenshot of the site in Safari: http://files.andrewjudd.ca/kiss-off-search.png

Darn Safari. Any ideas? I'll share my search bar and navigation bar's css & html, but I'd really appreciate anyone checking the full css/html of my website.

```
  #navigation {
position: fixed;
margin-top: 0;
left: 0;
top: 0;
right: 0;
width: 100%;
color: #ffffff;
height: 35px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 15px;
/* Adds shadow to the bottom of the bar */
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
/* Adds the transparent background */
background-color: rgba(125, 180, 18, 0.8);
color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
z-index: 900;
    }


    #search {
display: inline;
    }
    #search input[type="text"] {
display: inline;
background: url(search-white.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #fcfcfc;
border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
position: fixed;
margin-left: 450px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
color: #bebebe;
width: 150px;
padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
-webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
-moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
}

    #search input[type="text"]:focus {
width: 200px;
margin-right: 200px;
-o-margin-right: 10px;
display: inline;
}

/*SNIPPET OF HTML FOR NAVIGATION BAR & SEARCH HERE:*/
    <div id="navigation">
<div id="title">
KISS OFF
</div>
<form method="get" action="/search" id="search">
<input name="q" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Search..." />
</form>
<a href="#">Home</a>
<a href="#">Login</a>
<a href="#">Register</a>
<a href=#terms>Terms</a>
</div>
```

Thanks for looking, I appreciate it. :)
--Dijji

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change this:

```
#search input[type="text"]{
...
margin-left: 450px;
margin-right: 0px;
....
}
```

to

```
#search input[type="text"]{
...
float: right;
margin-right: 0px;
...
}
```

Hope that this solution can help you.

Comment: It still won't work in safari. Every time it is centered in safari, the transition is off. It's supposed to transition to the right.